# Rcpp Class wrap and as

Tags: rcpp

I created a Rcpp - Package with a Module that contains the following class :

**Update**

C++ Part:

```
class A
{
  public:
  void concat( A & x)
  {
   ....
  }
}
```

With the Rcpp Module - Part

```
RCPP_MODULE(Foo){
 using namespace Rcpp;

 class_<A>("A")
 .method("concat", &A::concat)
 ;
}
```

And the R - Part

```
x <- new(A)
y <- new(A)
```

**The Problem**

```
 x$concat(y)
```

**No known conversion from argument 1 'SEXP' to 'A'.**

The problem i think is that there is no specialized wrap and as function.
For me it is not clear, do i need the create this template function for the class A ?
Do i need to create a Rcpp:Xptr ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your question is.  You may want to expand a little, and I recommend you look at some existing packages using modules and/or start with a very simple one.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, hopefuly it is now clear ? :) greetings

Comment: Because R and Rcpp do not know what class `A` is, you have to create `as<>()` and `wrap()` accordingly.  This does not usually involve `XPtr`.

Comment: But for as<>() and wrap<>() it is necessary to generate R objects (ie lists of vecotor, dataframes ... ) with is not really possible. Is there a nother way ?

Comment: Or you can just use the supporting `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS` macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(A)` to generate all this stuff for you. See https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/macros/module.h for the details.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(A)

class A{
public:

    A(){}    

    void concat( A & x){
        Rprintf( "hello\n") ;
    }
} ;

RCPP_MODULE(Foo){
    using namespace Rcpp;

    class_<A>("A")
       .default_constructor()
       .method("concat", &A::concat)
    ;
}
```

Which gives:

```
> sourceCpp( "/tmp/mod.cpp" )
>
> a <- new(A)
> b <- new(A)
> a$concat(b)
hello
```